# Why is my variable (h) considered undeclared?

Tags: c, while-loop, cs50

I wrote a longer version of this code and had no problems but now I keep getting this error (error: use of undeclared identifier 'h') on my my 25th line (while (9 < h);). Please tell me what I'm doing wrong

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    do
    {
        int h = get_int("Height:");
        if (h < 9)
        {
            printf("%i\n", h);
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = j + 1; k < h; k++)
                    {
                        printf("#");
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
            }
        }
    } while (9 < h);

    {
        if (h > 0)
    }
}
```

I've tried switching the bracket placement but this is the only one that seems valid. Basically I'm expecting the the Height to be reask if the number enter isn't between 1-8. Any guesses why this isn't working? Also here's the longer version of my code that I'm attempting to shorten.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    // get height between 1 - 8
    int h = get_int("Height:");
    if (h < 9)
    {
        if (h > 0)
        {
            printf("%i\n", h);
            {
                // Rows
                for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
                {
                    // Columns
                    for (int k = j - 1; k < h; k++)
                    {
                        printf("#");
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int i;
        {
            // Loop if # outside 1-8 entered
            do
            {
                i = get_int("Valid Height:");
                {
                    printf("%i\n", i);
                    {
                        for (int l = 0; l < i; l++)
                        {
                            for(int m = 0; m < i; m++)
                            {
                                printf("#");
                            }
                            printf("\n");
                        }
                    }
                }

            } while (9 < i);

            {
                if (i > 0)
                {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `h` is declared inside the `do-while` loop. You can't access it outside the loop.

Comment: The condition of a for/do/while loop isn't part of the scope of the loop body. You could restructure the loop to exit by 'break'

Comment: You also have a syntax error. There's no body to the `if (h > 0)` statement.

Comment: If you want to use `h` after the loop is done, you need to declare it outside the loop.

Comment: @M.M That won't help with accessing it in the `if` statement later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `h` is undeclared because the variable is defined in the scope of the do-while, inside the curly braces, but the condition of the do-while loop isn't in the same scope. To fix this, at the beginning of `main()` add the line `int h;` and then remove the word `int` from the line `int h = get_int("Height:");`. Now your `h` variable will be declared. Also, an if with no body is a syntax error, so I added some brackets. With these changes, your first block of code will look like this:

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int h;
    do
    {
        h = get_int("Height:");
        if (h < 9)
        {
            printf("%i\n", h);
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = j + 1; k < h; k++)
                    {
                        printf("#");
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
            }
        }
    } while (9 < h);

    {
        if (h > 0)
        {
           /* some code */
        }
    }
}
```